# why NtUserInternalGetWindowText always return 0 in kernel mode

Tags: kernel, driver

I had replace NtUserShowWindow function in ssdt shadow with my own function MyNtUserShowWindow. but in MyNtUserShowWindow function, I invoke NtUserInternalGetWindowText function to try to get window title, but it always return 0(means failed). 
I don't know why?

some code blow:

```
BOOL MyNtUserShowWindow(
    IN HWND hWnd,
    IN int nCmdShow )
{
    LPWSTR buffer = NULL;
    SIZE_T memSize;
    int strLen;
    NTSTATUS status;

    memSize = MAX_PATH + 1;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(ZwAllocateVirtualMemory( ZwCurrentProcess(),
                                            &buffer,
                                            0,
                                            &memSize,
                                            MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE | MEM_TOP_DOWN,
                                            PAGE_READWRITE )))
    {
        strLen = NtUserInternalGetWindowText( hWnd, buffer, MAX_PATH );
        KdPrint(( "the get window len is %d, buffer is %S\n", strLen, buffer)); // strLen = 0

    }

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the answer, but you're allocating the wrong size buffer. You are allocating MAX_PATH+1 bytes, but telling NtUserInternalGetWindowText that the buffer is MAX_PATH WCHARs (MAX_PATH*2 bytes) long. Unless MAX_PATH is 1 (which it isn't), this may cause an access violation.

If the window you're looking at has a caption longer than MAX_PATH / 2 characters, this would cause the function to fail.

It is also possible that the window you're looking at belongs to a different process and is managing it's own window text - e.g. an edit control. You may want to take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx for an explanation of the times when GetWindowText (and one assumes by extension this undocumented method) will return something different.

Comment: thanks. I'm operating with normal window. After correct the buffer size, it's still failed. by the way, I think that the NtUserShowWindow or NtUserIntenalGetWindowText function is run in PASSIVE level, so it's no need to create memory in kernel mode, these address is in the same process. is it?